# Adding a subview to a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working with a UITableViewController with some cells. My problem is that I need to have a static button in front of the tableview but when I add the button view it moves up and down with the tableview scroll. 

This is my code in viewDidLoad:

```
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 55, self.view.frame.size.height - 55, 50, 50)];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[button layer]setMasksToBounds:YES];
[[button layer]setCornerRadius:25.0];

[self.view addSubview:button];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

And I add this line in the viewWillLayoutSubviews to support orientations:

```
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 55, self.view.frame.size.height - 55, 50, 50)];
```

I need to have the button static regardless the tableview content view offset. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

After testing your answers this solve my problem:

I add the `contentOffset.y` to my button's `setFrame` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method. I also try using `scrollView` delegate but didn't need it because the first method was doing all the work.

```
    - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 55, self.tableView.contentOffset.y + self.view.frame.size.height - 110, 50, 50)];
}
```

And that's it, the button stays static.

The extra minus 110 in the button's y origin are because the height and a `tabBar` that I have in my view.

Thanks to everyone. Your answers were really helpful.

Comment: Set the origin of the frame accordingly in scrollViewDidScroll: delegate method of UIScrollView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options here.

1. Convert to using a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` instead of using a `UITableViewController`. It shouldn't be much work and then you can add both your `UITableView` and your button as subviews of the root `UIView`.
2. If you want to keep using a `UITableViewController`, you will need to implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` and modify the frame of your button as the table is scrolled, to make it appear static. You also may want to add a `contentInset` to the table so that you can scroll the content past your custom view.

Comment: The OP might also be able to embed the table view controller in a navigation controller and add a bar button item to the navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks for the two options. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your `tableview` has only 1 section you can also add this `button` as the header of this section

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   // Build my view and return it
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   // Return the height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UITableViewController needs to be the `scrollViewDelegate` of the tableView.  Implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` to change your buttons frame/position.

One example is that setting your button's origin.y to `scrollView.contentOffset.y` should keep the button flush with the top of the tableView.